# foreach loop in php 5.3 and 7.2

Tags: php, mysql, foreach, php-7, php-5.3

I want to use this foreach loop in PHP 5.3 which is working fine in PHP 7.2

```
$query = sprintf("SELECT a,b FROM table");
$result = $mysqli->query($query);
$data = array();
foreach ($result as $row) {
 $data[] = $row;
}
```

I read the official documentation and got to know that foreach loop doesn't work the same way but I wasn't able to figure it out.

Comment: `foreach` works right down to version 4 http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php  - I doubt that that is causing the problem. You also didn't tell us what results you're getting as opposed to the desired results.

Comment: I don't see anything there that should be different between those two versions.

Comment: You're also not doing anything with the `sprintf()`. Least, not in what you posted. http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php - I.e. from the manual: `$num = 5;
$location = 'tree';

$format = 'There are %d monkeys in the %s';
echo sprintf($format, $num, $location);`.

Comment: Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [setuprate] => 15.180
            [Build] => 0.0.I5596
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [setuprate] => 15.490
            [Build] => 0.0.I5596
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [setuprate] => 15.530
            [Build] => 0.0.I5596
        )

) This is the output I am getting when I am printing the array in PHP 7.2.
But my array is not displaying anything in PHP 5.3 which I am using in centos. 
The $result variables are printing out to be the same in both case. So, I figured foreach is wrong

Comment: Oh wait, yeah I do.

Comment: **What** is the point of this line `$query = sprintf("SELECT a,b FROM table");` **copy/paste is fine** but the next step should be ___Read and Understand___

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're fetching results by iterating the result object with:

```
foreach ($result as $row) {
    $data[] = $row;
}
```

Support for that was not added until PHP 5.4. ([See the changelog in the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php)) You'll need to call a fetch method explicitly instead.

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $data[] = $row;
}
```

Comment: Impressive, that is quite a nuance. Have my +1